# SFSafariViewController Cancel at Prompt

Tags: ios, objective-c, sfsafariviewcontroller

Is there a way to detect if a user taps 'Cancel' vs 'Open' at a `SFSafariViewController` prompt.

For example, if it's a YouTube link and they have the YouTube app installed it will prompt to open YouTube. If I tap 'Cancel' then all that shows is an empty web view from `SFSafariViewController`. I'd like to load the url if the user taps 'Cancel'.

Comment: so when you tap on cancel the only delegate method for SFS VC not called ?

Comment: Correct, it's not called. I'm wondering if there's anything that detects the prompt so I can see what button index is pressed.